# Highest Coefficient of the glm() model in r

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to find the highest coefficient of the model produced by the glm() in r.

I know `summary()` will give me the details, but I will have to eyeball all the coefficients, and I have 25+ parameters. So is there any particular function or trick to do the same? This is my code, just incase,

```
fit.all <- glm(`Competitive?` ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train_data, control = list(maxit = 500)) 
coefs = fit.all$coefficients
```

Comment: Try `coefs[which.max(coefs)]`

Comment: Just to add to @DiceboyT great comment: You may need to take absolute values first: `coefs[which.max(abs(coefs))]` Oh, and the intercept should possibly be removed.